# Extracting coordinates (lat, lon) from MultiLineString GeoJSON in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, geojson

I want to make a ScatterMapbox map based on the information contained in this GeoJSON file: https://cdn.buenosaires.gob.ar/datosabiertos/datasets/metrobus/recorrido-de-metrobus.geojson .

However, I am facing the following problem: the geometry in the GeoJSON is a MultiLineString. I provide a written example of the problem here:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "callejero_badata_WGS84",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 28686, "codigo": 17138, "nomoficial": "PUNTA ARENAS", "alt_izqini": 0, "alt_izqfin": 0, "alt_derini": 0, "alt_derfin": 0, "nomanter": null, "nom_mapa": "TÚNEL PUNTA ARENAS", "tipo_c": "TÚNEL", "long": 334.60341680080836, "sentido": "DOBLE", "cod_sent": 2, "observa": "Viaducto - Túnel inaugurado en Abril de 2009", "bicisenda": "-", "lado_ciclo": null, "recorrid_x": null, "ciclo_obse": null, "tooltip_bi": null, "red_jerarq": "VÍA DISTRIBUIDORA COMPLEMENTARIA", "red_tp": null, "ffcc": "SI", "tipo_ffcc": "Túnel", "COMUNA": 15, "COM_PAR": 15, "COM_IMPAR": 15, "BARRIO": "PATERNAL", "BARRIO_PAR": "PATERNAL", "BARRIO_IMP": "PATERNAL" }, 
"geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": 
        [ [ [ -58.46939502613111, -34.590823162817173 ], 
        [ -58.469462454508552, -34.59098118466796 ], 
        [ -58.469669480276444, -34.591727559343369 ], 
        [ -58.469869735691702, -34.592625455739224 ], 
        [ -58.470073382303283, -34.593447590597258 ], 
        [ -58.470121607819273, -34.593775790374316 ] ] ] } }, ...
]
}
```

As you may see, the `coordinates` are composed by an array of lists (i.e. `[ [ [ -58.46939502613111, -34.590823162817173 ], [ -58.469462454508552, -34.59098118466796 ] ] ]`).

In order to plot the map, I need to extract from that file *ALL* the coordinates separately: all the latitudes must be on one list, and all the longitudes must be on another one. I would need something like this (following the example previously provided):

```
lats = [ -34.590823162817173,
         -34.59098118466796,
         -34.591727559343369,
         ...
       ]

lons = [ -58.46939502613111,
         -58.469462454508552,
         -58.469669480276444,
         ...
       ]
```

I tried several things, but got nothing close. Everything I did resulted in various errors and/or obtaining just one value/pair of values (coordinates) instead of the wanted list (above).

Everything I have now is the code where I load the GeoJSON, which I provide below.

```
metrobus = json.load(open("recorrido-de-metrobus.geojson"))
```

Is there any way to do something like this?

I really appreciate any advice, workaround or solution you might share with me. Thank you, in advance.

---

**EDIT 2**
Finally solved after following solution in this link: https://community.plotly.com/t/possible-bug-plotting-multipolygons-in-scattermapbox/33479 .

Thank you Yuri and fusion for your help.

Comment: How it should look like? Perhaps it doesn't make sense to join the dots in that sequence.

Comment: Hello! It should look something like this: https://www.buenosaires.gob.ar/sites/gcaba/files/mapa_mtb_caba_3_1.png .

Of course, ignore the background. I am just trying to plot the lines. 

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The sequence is matter: https://imgur.com/E7o3exh.png

Comment: But MultiLineString geometry IS actually used to join dots in space. Database is downloaded from a gov. entity, which they also use to plot maps and join dots in space. They also separate files with POINTS from files with MULTILINESTRING. I understand there must be something wrong, but I do not understand what's the error you are pointing out. Thank you for your response and help.

Comment: The coordinates (poins) look more or less correct https://imgur.com/7mbLKiT.png You need to figure out how to link these points. (If you need to link them)

Comment: It looks like you linked all the points. Perhaps there no need to draw lines between some points?

Comment: Again, thank you Yuri for your help. I do need to link them, and I believe that is what MultiLineString is all about: joining geo-spatial dots from given coordinates. I also believe the bottom line is that one shouldn't "decide" what points must (not) be joined, because that information is given in the MLS type. And that is the problem, actually: I still can't link ALL the coordinates of the GeoJSON in a given order. I really appreciate your help.

Edit regarding your new comment: what do you mean by "draw lines between some points"? Thank you.

Comment: *draw lines between some points* I'm afraid this was exactly about "to decide what points must (not) be joined". I see no solution If there are errors in the original data. Can it be not errors but deliberate distortions to make the date useless for anyone who has no a some special access key?

Comment: But I still think there are some bugs in your plotter. Look, all the dots on your screenshot are joined. I see no unjoined segments at all. But in the data most of the 'MultiLineString' looks like short lines that contain just two or three points. I'm sure that only points inside 'MultiLineStrings' should be joined (not between different 'MultiLineString'). So there should be hundreds of unjoined segments after all. Where they are? Even if most of the segments have common dots and look like joined there should be at least few unjoined "dead ends" out there.

Answer (score 1):

```py
# read your data:
metrobus = json.load(open("recorrido-de-metrobus.geojson"))

lats = []
lons = []

for i in data['features']:
    cord = i['geometry']['coordinates']
    for j in cord:
        for k in j:
            lats.append(k[1])
            lons.append(k[0])
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, this didn't quite solve the problem. There seems to be something "disordering" the pair of coordinates. Being more precise, it seems to me that coordinates have "merged": some latitudes and longitudes were mixed up. The result is a messy plot with an irregular disposition of lines. I am sorry I can't include an image on the comment (I will proceed to edit the original post). Again, thank you for your help.